# Under what condition does $\int_a^b|f(x)|=0$ imply $f=0$? ( at least a.e.).

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, normed-spaces

I'm working through Real Analysis by Royden & Fitzpatrick, and on the first section on $L^p$ spaces they always skip the last property of norms without much commentary. Namely, that $||f||=0 \iff f=0$.

For example, they discuss a norm of $L^1$ given by $||f||=\int_a^bx^2|f(x)|dx$. To show $||f||=0 \implies f=0$, they just claim $\int_a^bx^2|f(x)|dx=0$ gives $f=0$ a.e.

Unfortunately, I do not see how this is immediately obvious, neither from the definition of Riemann or Lebesgue integration. Is this somehow trivial for non negative functions? I've seen some proofs of this for continuous functions, but $f\in L^1$ and is not necessarily continuous here.

Comment: Integral is riemann sum, and if sum of non - negative numbers is zero.. then what does that imply?

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi Thanks, I see that for non-negative functions. Not sure if there is a theorem that clears this up for a greater class of functions.

Comment: why non - negative functions? it must imply $f = 0$ irrespective of whether $f$ is positive or negative, because you' re taking riemann sum of $|f|$

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi What about $f(x)=x$ over $[-a,a]$. Then $\int_{-a}^ax=0$ but $f(x)=x$ is not zero.

Comment: In $L^p$ theory, always use the Lebesgue integral.  (If you use Riemann, your space will not be complete.)

Comment: @GEdgar I did and then I accidentally accepted someone's edit who turned it into Riemann. I'm fixing it back now.

Comment: No, but  I suppose you're asking how does $\int_a^b|f(x)|dx = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0 \ \mathbb{for \ all \ x \in (a, b)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) if $f$ is measurable, and $\int_a^b |f(t)|\;dt = 0$, then $f(t) = 0$ for almost all $t$.

*Proof*.  Suppose $|\{t : f(t) \ne 0\}| > 0$.  (I used $|\cdot|$ for Lebesgue measure.)  Then $|\{t : |f(t)|>0\}| > 0.$  But
$$
\{t : |f(t)|>0\} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \left\{t : |f(t)| > \frac{1}{n}\right\}
$$
so by countable additivity, there exists $n$ such that
$\left|\left\{t : |f(t)| > \frac{1}{n}\right\}\right| > 0$.  Thus
$$
\int_a^b |f(t)|\;dt \ge \left|\left\{t : |f(t)| > \frac{1}{n}\right\}\right|\cdot\frac{1}{n} > 0.
$$

(2) If $f$ is measurable, and $\int_a^b t^2|f(t)|\;dt = 0$, then $f(t) = 0$ for almost all $t$.

Applying (1) to the function $t^2|f(t)|$, we get $t^2|f(t)|=0$ for almost all $t$.  The points where $f(t)$ are zero, together with (possibly) one point where $t^2=0$, give us the points where $t^2 |f(t)| = 0$.  So from $t^2|f(t)|=0$ a.e. we get $f(t)=0$ a.e.

Comment: thanks this is very insightful

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\leq t\leq b$.

As $x^2|f(x)|\geq0$,
$$0\leq\int_a^t x^2|f(x)|dx\leq\int_a^b x^2|f(x)|dx$$
So, for any $a\leq t\leq b$,
$$\int_a^t x^2|f(x)|dx=0$$
Now differentiate it and you get
$$t^2|f(t)|=0\quad (a\leq t\leq b)$$
$$|f(t)|=0\quad (a\leq t\leq b, t\ne0)$$
$$\therefore f(t)=0\quad (a\leq t\leq b, t\ne0)$$

Comment: So $f(x)$ could be $\delta(x)$ [Dirac-Delta function] if $a\leq0\leq b$. And then $f(x)\ne0$.?

Comment: The above relies on the fact that $f$ be continuous -- [the generalization of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to merely locally integrable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations) will give something similar, but slightly different.